# Using makeObjectsPerformSelector with an object

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have an `NSArray` of objects and I want to perform the selector `pinInBackgroundWithName:(NSString *)` on each object. I know that I can use `[arr makeObjectsPerformSelector:@selector(selector_name) withObject:obj];` but how does passing in the string to the `withObject:` argument work? For example, what if the selector I wanted to perform on the objects in the array had multiple arguments? Then would the `withObject:` argument we an `NSArray` of objects?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the docs:

> A selector that identifies the message to send to the objects in the array. The method must take a single argument of type `id`

So you can't use this for a selector with multiple arguments.

If you want to send a message with multiple arguments to each object in the array, you could roll your own version that takes an array, and then fills out an `NSInvocation` object that it then invokes on each object, or, if you wanted to be really fancy, use higher order messaging.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest ditching the selector-based calls and using `enumerateObjectsUsingBlock` or one of it's variants.

Blocks inherit their enclosing scope, so you can invoke a block of code that uses as many variables as you want from the scope of the call.